# Div not filling Height

Tags: html, css

Working to help a student with his project trying to get his Div to fill up the full body of the page.

I've tried following the various examples with HTML and BODY tag being set to 100% however when I set the minimum height for my Div it does not fill with the complete height of the page.  Here is my code.  When it renders the green should fill the page but it doesn't.

Thanks KT

```
<html>
<center>
<head>

    <link href="styles.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="tblwrap" height="100%">    
    <table  class="scndtable" >
            <tr class="headerrow">
                <td height=100%><a href="summary.html">Summary</a> </td>
                <td><a href="map.html">Map</a> </td>
                <td><a href="videos.html">Videos</a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
    <p style="font-weight: bold;text-align: center;"> </p>

</body>
</center>
```

Here is my CSS

```
html
{
height:100%;
}
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;


vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
border: 20px solid skyblue;
}
body table
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;

}
.tblwrap
{
background-color:green;
min-height: 100%;

    vertical-align: middle;
border:solid 3px red;
}
.headerrow{
text-align: center;

}
.scndtable
{
border-spacing:20px;
height: 100%;

}
.headerrow td{
font-size: 20pt;


background-color:silver;

}
.headerrow td a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
.headerrow td a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: gray;
}
.selectednav
{   
font-size: 72px;
font-weight: bold;
color:navy;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  .tblwrap{position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:green;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border:solid 3px red;
    oveflow:auto;
    }
```

This will work for you:-)

Comment: This will never stretch above the full height of the page though

Comment: div scrollbar will behave like body scrollbar with no difference

Comment: Assuming the entire webpage will be inside the div

Comment: Thanks you solved not only the problem but were a useful tool into introducing my student to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to recreate your issue in JSFiddle before you ask your question on StackOverflow. I tried to recreate your particular problem, but in my case the div easily stretches the height of the viewport:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWGVr/

But as with Ankit Gautam's solution, this will always cover the height of the viewport, never stretching further